# handling infinity values in JSON

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I need at one place to have the support for infinity, -infinity and NaN values in my JSON. Now though JSON does have support for these values, but is there any support for specifying about them in the schema of the same JSON instance, I mean the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-6) specification says that these values are not supported under "number" type. However, when I validated one such JSON instance having infinity value against a schema with the type "number", it produced no error! Can someone help me to figure out why is this happening, and also if "number" type discards these values, how can I define the type of these values inside JSON schema. Here is my schema and instance which I used to validate.

Schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
        "properties": {
        "lower_bound": {"type": "number"}
        }
}
```

JSON instance being validated:

```
{
    "lower_bound": Infinity
}
```

Comment: Your json instance is not valid, as the answer below states.

Comment: Not sure where that "JSON Instance" is coming from but if you get it with `json.load`or `json.loads` you can use the `parse_constant=` keyword to raise an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON does not support neither infinity or NaN values (and never has, since the original json.org grammar). Neither does JSON Schema (because it is only defined for RFC8259-compliant JSON documents or structures).

This is due to interoperability reasons - otherwise each target language that does not support infinities or NaNs would need to always wrap these values.

Whether some validator accepts invalid json documents - does not really matter. They are still invalid.

Comment: So, it looks like we can not define support for infinity values in JSON schema. Though, one possible way which I think can be is to define the type of "lower_bound" in above instance as number or string, and when infinity values come, we can parse them in string, isn't it?

Comment: I guess... you know your requirements better than I do :)