# Can infinity be stored in a SQLite JSON1 column?

Tags: python, json, sqlite, sqlalchemy, sqlite-json1

#### Use Case

I'm using SQLAlchemy and SQLite for a standalone application (non-web) and I need to store numerical ranges in a database. I'm doing this by saving the start and end of each range in SQLite like so:

```py
[[float("-inf"), 0], [1, 1000],..., [9999, 12000], [12001, float("inf")]]
```

In the final application I need to determine what range an arbitrary `number` falls within. I'm doing something like below:

```py
...
for range_ in ranges:
    range_start, range_end = range_
    if range_start <= number <= range_end:
        return range_
...
```

`number` can be any integer or infinity so the ranges in the db ***must*** stretch from negative infinity to positive infinity

#### Problem

The following code works fine

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker, scoped_session


Base = declarative_base()


class MyMappedClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ranges = sa.Column(sa.JSON)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite://", future=True)
    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

    session = Session()
    Base.metadata.create_all(session.bind)
    mapped_class = MyMappedClass(
        ranges=[[float("-inf"), 1], [1, float("inf")]],
    )
    with session:
        session.add(mapped_class)
        session.commit()
```

But when I add a `CheckConstraint` calling `json_array_length(ranges)` I get a `malformed JSON` error:

```py
...
ranges = sa.Column(
    sa.JSON,
    sa.CheckConstraint("json_array_length(ranges) >= 2"),
)
...
```

Traceback:

```
...
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) malformed JSON
...
```

I confirmed `[[float("-inf"), 1], [1, float("inf")]]` isn't being converted to valid JSON by changing the `CheckConstraint` to `json_valid(ranges)` and it fails only when infinity is in the column.

I **must** be able to add `CheckConstraint`s to the `ranges` column. There are data validation steps I need to do with other columns. The details of which are complex and beyond the scope of this question.

#### Workarounds

I think I can get around this by replacing `float("inf")` with `"inf"` like so

```py
mapped_class = MyMappedClass(
    ranges=[["-inf", 1], [1, "inf"]],
)
```

And I can determine the range of an arbitrary `number` like:

```py
...
for range_ in ranges:
    range_start, range_end = range
    if float(range_start) <= number <= float(range_end):
        return range_
...
```

But now I have mixed types in the column and I would prefer only numbers present.

#### Back to the Question

Is there any way to store infinity in a JSON1 column? If there are other databases that support infinity in an array (that are suitable for a standalone application) please share. Ideally, SQLAlchemy supports this database.

Comment: I am unsure that the JSON spec supports *infinity* for numbers, to start with.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61841001/2144390

Comment: @GordThompson if you put that link in an answer, I'll accept it.